# iOS: Using Three20 TTPhoto with NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, core-data, three20

I am using [Three20](http://three20.info)'s TTPhoto with `NSManagedObject`:

```
@interface Photo : NSManagedObject <TTPhoto> {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * caption;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Album * photoSource;

// ...

@end
```

The above properties are given by Core Data (My Album class does comply to the `TTPhotoSource` protocol). Now, my problem is that the `TTPhoto` protocol requires slightly different properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * caption;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TTPhotoSource> photoSource;
```

How can I make the `NSManagedObject` properties comply to the `TTPhoto` protocol (mind the difference in retain vs. copy/assign)?

(the photo.m files contains the standard `@dynamic` caption, `@dynamic` `photoSource`)